# Generating a vector of pair items using STL in C++

Tags: c++, stl

I want to generate a vector of `{i, 0}` pairs where i goes from 0 to n - 1, using the STL `generate` function and my current code looks like this

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> new_vertex(n);    
int i = -1;
std::generate(new_vertex.begin(), new_vertex.end(), [&]{
  i += 1;
  return {i, 0};
});
```

My question is that is there a much better/cooler way to do this using a STL function, like using `transform` in some wierd way, preferably one that removes the use of the variable declaration `int i = -1` on top ?

Comment: With Eric's [Ranges library](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), which should eventually make its way into the standard, you can generate an infinite list of 0, 1, 2, ..., then transform those into {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}, ..., then take the first n of them, or even keep it as is and let whatever is using it take what it needs.

Comment: I think this is a good solution. Using [std::transform()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) requires `N` iterations and so does [std::generate()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate). So from a performance standpoint, it's the same.

Comment: Yes, but I doubt anyone would approve this is a good programming practice. Think about it, I can define `i` anywhere and it can be manipulated 20 different ways. before `generate` executes. My basic question is that given the huge size of the C++ standard, is there a better/safer way than this?

Comment: @suyash: Take a look at the [capture clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293608.aspx) of the lambda expression; but you still have to declare the counter in a surrounding scope.

Comment: using `generate` isn't a strict requirement for this

Comment: You can wrap this in its own scope: `{ int i= ... }` which keeps the counter constrained. If you'd like to step outside of the C++ standard, you could also  consider gcc's [nested functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html). To avoid declaring `i` what you'd ultimately want is a [Python style closure/generator](https://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/04/07/improve-your-python-yield-and-generators-explained/), not sure if [C++ lambda closures](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html) provide this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++14. I'd make the counter private to the lambda. I'd also not initialize the vector elements unnecessarily:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

v.reserve(n);

std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(v), n,
                [i = 0]() mutable { return std::make_pair(i++, 0); });
```